# Log something to a lead Activity History other than calls?

Tags: apex, history-tracking

I'm interested on logging items to user activity like "Attended an event", "Visited shop", "Opened Email".

Is it possible to use Activity History to log this actions?

If not could I create a custom pane in the lead page, similar to Activity History?

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible? It is not only possible, it is trivial to do so. Just create a Task and assign the Type that makes sense to you, such as as "Attended an event" or "Opened email". (You will probably have to add these values as picklist values on the Type field.) If you want to reflect that the action has already happened in the past, set the Due Date to that date and set the Status to "Completed".

You can also set up custom buttons with "hacked" URLs that automatically default these values for you: https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=90630000000hOSHAA2

Can you create a custom pane on the Lead page? Technically, yes - but you would have to use Visualforce. In general, most people just make the Type field visible on the Activity History related list and sort on that field to figure out what the various activities associated with this Lead are.

Good luck!